# Python if/else/elif always goes to else

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm creating a program for a school assignment that uses python to give basic info on elements on the periodic table. I'm using if/elif/else and print in order to do this. After I got all the if/elif/else statements down I went to test it, and when I type anything in it goes to the else condition, even if I type in something that should go to an elif statement. Code is too long to paste here so I put it in a document [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/14Sa8pGMML4YmtI20WiWugQsR0YmtenIDW7K023z2koI/edit?usp=sharing) Python version is 3.6.4

Comment: This question isn't answerable. Please post a minimal example in-question. Dumping your homework assignment and saying "Why doesn't this work" isn't even halfway to the least amount of effort that's expected of asking a question here.

Comment: Delete code from your answer until it either fixes the problem or you can't delete any more and still run the code in the `else` statement, then post that minimized code here.

Comment: There are some errors. `"ele" == input("")` does not assign the input to a variable called `"ele"`, you instead want `ele = input("")`. And then on all of the logical comparisons, you need to get rid of `"ele"` and replace it with the variable `ele`. Right now, as it stands you are literally checking if there is an element on the periodic table with the symbol `"ele"` on every single comparison. Since there is no such element,  it goes to the `else` clause

Comment: ^^^ Thank you! I'm really new to coding with python so I'm not surprised that I made such a simple mistake like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder how you are able to run this program, seems to be some harry potter stuff. For me its typo in this line `"ele" == input("")` and gives Syntax error . So just fix this with `ele = input()` and replace **"ele"** with **ele** in all if/elif checks i.e `if ele == "H":`it will work as intended.